# WinExec shellcode

Tags: assembly, shellcode

Can anyone help me implement a winexec to execute commands or to start cmd.exe using x86 asm ?

Below is an example on how i used msvcrt.system to spawn cmd.exe ! i want to do the same with winexec please.

```
00446001   68 65786500      PUSH 657865 // exe
00446006   8BDC             MOV EBX,ESP
00446008   68 636D642E      PUSH 2E646D63 // cmd.
0044600D   8BCC             MOV ECX,ESP
00446010   53               PUSH EBX
00446011   51               PUSH ECX
00446012   E8 B0337E77      CALL msvcrt.system
00446017   90               NOP
```

Answer (score 3):

you can try one of this two variants (one of them is commented)

```
;mov eax,1
;push eax
;call there
;db "notepad.exe c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts",0
;there:
;call WinExec

push  "sts"
push  "oh\c"
push  "te\s"
push  "revi"
push  "rd\2"
push  "3met"
push  "sys\"
push  "swod"
push  "niw\"
push  ".\:c"
push  " exe"
push  ".dap"
push  "eton"
mov eax,esp ; the last one pushed is the head of the string
push 1
push eax
call WinExec

add esp,52 ; restore stack state (13 pushes)
xor eax,eax
push eax
call ExitProcess
```

Comment: Does MASM actually reverse the order of multi-character constants?  That's inconvenient.  In NASM, `push 'abcd'` will result in a, b, c, d in memory from low to high addresses, same order as with `db 'abcd'`.

Comment: @PeterCordes , yes it was tested on MASM, i have no experiance with NASM.

Comment: `call there` will include some zero bytes, making this not work as shellcode.  Normally you'd `jmp rel8` forwards and `call` backwards, because a negative displacement won't have any zero bytes.  To zero-terminate the string, though, you probably need to store a zero so the shellcode can be free from zeros.

Comment: @PeterCordes, you are right. I wanted to demonstrate how to push strings using call. Still threre are other problems to solve before this code can be ready to be used as shellcode. Eg: resolving the address of the finctions WinExec and ExitProcess